# Issue with creating radio buttons in a pdf using iText7

Tags: java, itext7

Below is the code for creating a Radio Button in the table

```
public class RadioButtonRender extends CellRenderer {
    protected String name;
    protected String[] value;

    public RadioButtonRender(Cell modelElement, String name, String[] value) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(drawContext.getDocument(), true);
        PdfButtonFormField group = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(drawContext.getDocument(), "", "");

        float x = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft();
        float y = (getOccupiedAreaBBox().getTop() + getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom()) / 2;

        System.out.println(x + "      " + y);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
            PdfFormField.createRadioButton(drawContext.getDocument(), rect, group,
                    this.value[i]);         
        }

        form.addField(group);
    }
}
```

This is the code where I call RadioButtonRender and add that cell to the table, but Somehow radio buttons are not added to the table but checkboxes, text fields are working fine

```
    cell.setNextRenderer(
                        new RadioButtonRender(cell, entry.getString(), values.toArray(new String[values.size()])));
   table.addCell(cell);
```

I am sure I am not sending any null values in **values** list, So that might not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you don't see the result is that you haven't set the name of the radio group and its value. Radio group manages the states of its child radio buttons, and this it should have an initial value. It also must have a name.

Change the line that creates the radio group into

```
PdfButtonFormField group = PdfFormField.createRadioGroup(drawContext.getDocument(), "fieldName", this.value[0]);
```

And you will see that now a radio button is selected (black circle is displayed). Note that passing value is not mandatory, but if you don't pass the initial value, no radio buttons would be initially selected.

Also, the coordinates inside your `for` loop are independent of loop `i` variable, this you are drawing all the radio buttons one on top of the other.

Finally, you might want to draw some content near the buttons to indicate their values. E.g. you might add that content into cell and call `super.draw(drawContext);`.